# How to perform key-restricted broadcast-operate-update in Pandas?

Tags: pandas

The following is a simple toy example of the type of operation I want to do.

Suppose that I have two Pandas `DataFrame`s `df0` and `df1`, like these:

```
In [2]: df0
Out[2]: 
   A   B  C
0  v  67  7
1  u  30  8
2  v  71  9
3  u  31  1
4  u  27  1
5  v  60  7
6  v  78  9
7  u  41  7

In [3]: df1
Out[3]: 
   A   B
0  u  20
1  v  10
```

Note that all the columns of `df1` are in `df0`.  Also note that, the values in `df1['A']` are unique, and in fact they represent all the values that appear (with repeats) in `df0['A']`.

I want to subtract `df1['B']` from `df0['B']` *in place*, by *broadcasting* `df0['B']` into the right shape according to the value of the `A` column.  (With the end result that `20` gets subtracted from the `B` field of all the rows of `df0` that have `u` in their `A` field; and likewise, `10` gets subtracted from the `B` field of all the rows of `df0` that have `v` in their `A` field).

The goal is to end up with `df0` looking like the following:

```
In [4]: df0
Out[4]: 
   A   B  C
0  v  57  7
1  u  10  8
2  v  61  9
3  u  11  1
4  u   7  1
5  v  50  7
6  v  68  9
7  u  21  7
```

As I said at the beginning, this is just a toy example.  I'm interested in doing this sort of key-restricted updating with more operations than just subtraction.

What is the simplest way to do this sort of thing with Pandas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can also be done using apply, no need to sort.

```
In [188]: def f(s):
   .....:     s['B'] -= df1.loc[df1.A == 'v', 'B'].iat[0]
   .....:     return s
   .....: 


In [189]: df0.apply(f, axis=1)
Out[189]: 
   A   B  C
0  v  57  7
1  u  20  8
2  v  61  9
3  u  21  1
4  u  17  1
5  v  50  7
6  v  68  9
7  u  31  7
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this will be robust enough to handle any situation you might dream up, but indexing by column "A" will provide you the match/operation functionality.

```
df0.set_index("A", inplace=True)
df1.set_index("A", inplace=True)

df2 = df0.sort()

df2["B"] = df2["B"] - df1["B"]
```

Comment: Sorry, didn't get to test this, sorting should take care of it.